# Blazor WASM, How to implement custom post OIDC login logic

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm application that i've integrated with identity server 4. All is well until i try to load up an initial state of the user based on some db assets. This was trivial in pages or mvc where i owned the login page. Now it seems i can either store the assets as claims (which could create hundreds/thousands of claims for the user), or figure out a way to override the login flow to include and additional step.

Unfortunately my google-fu is not on point with this, as i search for "blazor wasm override oidc sign-in" or something similar i get results for setting up blazor + oidc, which i've already done. I tried reading the blazor docs, but i wouldn't be surprised if i missed something, or if it went over my head. If anyone can point me to a doc, or show me the setting / class i'd need to implement/override i'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much user data are we talking? You should look into implementing the `IPorfileService` as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#profile-service

That will give you the extensibility you are looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks Cory, I could utilize the claims, however the hierarchy could get rather large. However if that's the way we're going then i'll have to succumb. But here's my scenario: we have a list of companies with a list of employees. each employee can be part of multiple companies and has 7 permissions for each company, (editUsers, editOrders, editSchedule, etc). and just because he's able to manage users at company a doesn't mean he could at company b. Realistically a person may have access to 2 or 3, but i can't ignore the edge case where someone would have 70 claims (company + permission)

Comment: Perhaps you change how/when you check for these claims? Without diving too deep into app functionality, is it possible to only request the claims as needed? E.g., when a user selects a particular company to perform an action on?

Comment: That is possible, I guess I misunderstood what's in the token and was expecting it to contain ALL the claims. and when making calls between api, client, and identity provider wanted to keep the jwt as small as possible.